# What is the equation to use to determine the sum of multisets, size 3, with their members being from a given size of X

Tags: combinatorics

*EDIT* People in the comments have been really helpful at explaining terminology I am using that is wrong/confusing. I've come to learn the correct way I should be asking this is "What is the equation to find the sum of multisets of size three with their members being from a given set of size X? (In my case X=6).

I have a project that has 6 characters in it (we can call them A,B,C,D,E,F for sanity). If I wanted to determine how many unique groups of 3 I could make with these 6 characters (with the assumption that A,A,B = A,B,A = B,A,A and thus only counts as 1 unique comp), what formula would I use to determine this equation?

I believe if I wanted unique sets of 2, I would use (n(n-1))/2 but I am unsure first if this is correct and second how to scale this to work with triplets. I want to say it would just then be (n(n(n-1)))/3 but am unsure if that is correct (pretty sure those two equations spit out the same result because nothing really changes).

Also, how would the formula change if I wanted to find unique pairs of 4 under the same rules?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets

Comment: I am always put off by people using "unique" like this. Is it just a bad way of saying "distinct" (which here is superfluous because it is implied by "number of"), or is there more to it? Maybe giving an example of a composition that is rejected because it is not unique would help.

Comment: I thought my example of a combination containing a non-unique/distinct number was clear but maybe I was mistaken. Due to me having three positions for every variable to be in (such as A,A,A or A,B,C etc.) I will run into instances where I will get a unique/distinct composition that is just a variation of an already existing combination (for example F,F,A and A,F,F are "unique" as variable positioning is different but I consider them to be the same combination even with the variables in different positions.

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation. So my criticism has two parts. The first is using "unique" as a relation _between_ things, as in "for example F,F,A and A,F,F are unique", which is just linguistically wrong; if you want to say (as I think you do) "for example F,F,A and A,F,F are distinct", that is how to say it. Use of "unique" should be relative to a specification, as in "each country has a unique head of state", meaning one cannot have two distinct things satisfying the specification (here two distinct people both head of state of the same country). ...

Comment: ... The second point is that often what is really meant is that one wants things that _a priori_ are distinct to be considered equivalent, and count equivalence classes. That is a common thing to want to do, and perfectly fine, but it requires being explicit about what equivalence relation is intended; just dropping the magic term "unique" (or "distinct" for that matter) does not resolve the obligation. Here you meant to say that distinct groups of $3$ letters, like (A,A,B) and (B,A,A), are to be considered equivalent if each letter occurs in either of the two the same number of times.

Comment: ... That corresponds to the notion of multiset (with members from a given set $S$); by definition such a multiset assigns to every element of $S$ a multiplicity (a natural number) and two such multisets are the same if for every member of $S$ the two assign the same multiplicity to it. So the desired notion of equivalence among groups of three letters becomes that of _equality_ of the multisets they represent, and by talking about multisets you can avoid the vagueness of "uniqueness". So your question is how many multisets of size $3$ with their members from a given set of size $6$ there are.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen appreciates the teachings and clarification on proper vocabulary. I'll make sure to edit my question so others reading it don't need to search through the comments to understand what I am looking for. With that being said, do you know the equation that is used to determine the answer to this? And if so, could you share it?

Comment: @Melacsirrah: the answer is given in my comment from 5 days ago. Take $n = 6, k = 3$.